# ASP.NET Core Web API: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my first attempt at a .NET API and using .NET core. I used to be able to use ADO.NET to connect the database to the project but apparently that isn't supported anymore so I used EF Core using these packages: microsoft.entityframeworkcore\5.0.8, microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\5.0.6, and microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\5.0.6.

I then generated the model and db context for both tables in the database which seems to have worked fine. However, when I try to access localhost/api/Statewides I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TestAPI.Models.RoadWay_HistoryContext' while attempting to activate 'TestAPI.Controllers.StatewidesController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
Host: localhost:44324
Referer: https://localhost:44324/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

I really don't have any idea what this means... I'm going to provide the DB context and the model as well as the controller and startup files. If you need anything else to answer this question I will happily provide it.

#### Statewides Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestAPI.Models;

namespace TestAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StatewidesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly RoadWay_HistoryContext _context;

        public StatewidesController(RoadWay_HistoryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Statewides
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Statewide>>> GetStatewides()
        {
            return await _context.Statewides.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Statewides/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Statewide>> GetStatewide(long id)
        {
            var statewide = await _context.Statewides.FindAsync(id);

            if (statewide == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return statewide;
        }

        // PUT: api/Statewides/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutStatewide(long id, Statewide statewide)
        {
            if (id != statewide.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(statewide).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StatewideExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Statewides
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Statewide>> PostStatewide(Statewide statewide)
        {
            _context.Statewides.Add(statewide);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStatewide", new { id = statewide.Id }, statewide);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Statewides/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteStatewide(long id)
        {
            var statewide = await _context.Statewides.FindAsync(id);
            if (statewide == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Statewides.Remove(statewide);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool StatewideExists(long id)
        {
            return _context.Statewides.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Statewide.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace TestAPI.Models
{
    public partial class Statewide
    {
        public Statewide()
        {
            DocumentsNavigation = new HashSet<Document>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string SignSys { get; set; }
        public string RouteNoOrigImport { get; set; }
        public int? RouteNo { get; set; }
        public int? SuppDes { get; set; }
        public string LocalName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateNumber { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string OriginalL { get; set; }
        public string OriginalD { get; set; }
        public string Projects { get; set; }
        public string Documents { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public int? District { get; set; }
        public bool DuplicateOk { get; set; }
        public string RightofWay { get; set; }
        public bool ReservedRoute { get; set; }
        public string ReservedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReservedDate { get; set; }
        public bool CpWorkCompleted { get; set; }
        public string WorkComments { get; set; }
        public string CpProjectNo { get; set; }
        public int? ReservedCat { get; set; }
        public string AddUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Document> DocumentsNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### DB context

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

#nullable disable

namespace TestAPI.Models
{
    public partial class RoadWay_HistoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public RoadWay_HistoryContext()
        {
        }

        public RoadWay_HistoryContext(DbContextOptions<RoadWay_HistoryContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Statewide> Statewides { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=dotb6gisdbst01;Database=RoadWay_History;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.AddUser)
                    .HasMaxLength(25)
                    .HasColumnName("Add_User");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateAdded)
                    .HasColumnType("date")
                    .HasColumnName("Date_Added");

                entity.Property(e => e.DocLocation)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("Doc_Location");

                entity.Property(e => e.DocType)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("Doc_Type");

                entity.Property(e => e.FileContents)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("File_Contents");

                entity.Property(e => e.OrderDate)
                    .HasColumnType("date")
                    .HasColumnName("Order_Date");

                entity.Property(e => e.StatewideId).HasColumnName("Statewide_ID");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Statewide)
                    .WithMany(p => p.DocumentsNavigation)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.StatewideId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Documents_Statewide");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Statewide>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Statewide");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.AddUser)
                    .HasMaxLength(25)
                    .HasColumnName("Add_User");

                entity.Property(e => e.County)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("COUNTY");

                entity.Property(e => e.CpProjectNo)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("CP_ProjectNo");

                entity.Property(e => e.CpWorkCompleted).HasColumnName("CP_WorkCompleted");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateAdded)
                    .HasColumnType("date")
                    .HasColumnName("Date_Added");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateNumber).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.DuplicateOk).HasColumnName("Duplicate OK");

                entity.Property(e => e.LocalName).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.Method).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.OriginalD).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.OriginalL).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.ReservedDate).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.RightofWay).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.RouteNoOrigImport).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.SignSys).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.WorkComments)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("Work_Comments");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TestAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TestAPI v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you have not registered `RoadWay_HistoryContext` to the services container. All services used through dependency injection have to be registered. This is how the classes are able to resolve the services when you attempt to use them. This is how you fix it by adding this line to the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddDbContext<RoadWay_HistoryContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionName")));
```

**Update**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionName": "Server=ServerOfDatabase;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. 2 questions: Where can I find "my connection name"? I thought RoadWay_HistoryContext was the name... and 2nd, could you by chance point me to a good docs for this? I can't find the correct documentation to work on this to save my life.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 Ideally, you would place it in appsettings.development.json. I would update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Place what in appsettings.development.json? The connection name? I can do that I guess, but I have to find my connection name first. What is my connection name and how do I find it? Like I said I thought that RoadWay_HistoryContext was the connection name. I do not know what the connection name is. I do not remember ever being asked for or declaring a "Connection Name"

Comment: The connection name can be anything. It's just a variable whose value is your database connection string

Comment: I'm sorry I'm terribly confused. Are you telling me to create a variable in appsettings.development.json something like connectionName = "Server=dotb6gisdbst01;Database=RoadWay_History;Trusted_Connection=True;" ?

Comment: If I do that I get this error: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Comment: No where in my app have I defined any kind of connection name. I did not know I had to do this anywhere. My connection string is "Server=dotb6gisdbst01;Database=RoadWay_History;Trusted_Connection=True;" but it does not have a "name". It has not been assigned to any variable anywhere. I'm not sure what you're telling me to do but I'd love to understand.

Comment: Yes, something like that. If you get that error, it means the variable doesn't exist or there's name mismatch somewhere because it basically means it can't find anything called connectionString in the environmental variables

Comment: Currently, based on what you have shown, the project doesn't know anything abou the connection string to the database. Can you edit your appsettings where you defined the connection strings into the question or anywhere you defined it?

Comment: Ok I used that code that you updated in your question which seems to have worked but now I get this: Win32Exception: The network path was not found.
Unknown location

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Can you try to login to the database with the same database credentials in the connection string to be sure they correct

Comment: I figured it out it was a silly mistake. Thank you so much for the help!